# Broadcast Receiver doesn't read current value in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I have a settings activity with an edit text preference which save in shared preferences a string which is an IP address, then I have a broadcast reciever where a AsyncTask makes a call to a service. I would like to make customizable url address,  but when I make the call is not taken the current value of the ip address, but when I restart my app is taken the right value. How could I solve this issue. I paste only the useful code.
Thanks in advance

```
public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        new Call().execute();

}



private class Call extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String ip;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ip = preferences.getString("key","");


        String result = RestFullConnection.postCall("http://" + ip + ":8080/app/api/bla/sync", params[0]);
        return result;

    }

}
```

+++ edit +++
I call broadcast in the MainActivity and I save the value in the SP using EditTextPreference :

```
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Broadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 5000, 30 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Where and when is the broadcast triggered? And post the code where you save the ip.

Comment: I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this in onReceive

```
preferenze = context.getSharedPreferences(PERFERENCE_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Hope it will Help you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you save your SharedPreferences. Using the `apply()` method will store the value asynchronously so it won't block the current Thread. `commit()` on the other hand saves the value immediately. This *may* an issue in your case (please provide your code where you save your SharedPreferences).

Be careful, that SharedPreferences don't work correctly across different Processes! If you're using different processes I recommend using some mechanism that works with it (e.g. IPC, Databases, ...).

An alternative library which replaces SharedPreferences is [Tray](https://github.com/grandcentrix/Tray). It uses Content Provider/Databases and has a similar Syntax. You even can import existing data from SharedPreferences.

Comment: as I wrote in my question, I do not save the value programmatically, but use a component (edittextpreference) that does it for me

Comment: It still has the stated problems - iirc the `EditTextPreference` uses `apply()`.

Comment: Now that we've understand the problem, Which could be the solution?

Comment: Don't use the EditTextPreference.